# Count Blank Cells in Column

Tags: excel, report, formula, excel-2013

I have a report that varies in length from month to month because of hires and terminations so last month I had 8354 total employees and this month 8683 total employees. Column Y gives me the Medical Plan the employee is on and it will be blank if the employee does not have medical coverage.

How may I count the total of populated cells and blank cells taking into consideration the total number of employees?

I tried using COUNTA() but its going all the way down to the last row in Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To take the difference between the blank cells in ColumnA (say those that do not contain an employee ID, name or such like) and the blank cells in ColumnY (some of which are blank despite an entry in ColumnA for the same row) please try:

```
=COUNTBLANK(Y:Y)-COUNTBLANK(A:A)
```

Comment: This answers the number of blank cells, but how about the number of populated cells in the Y column?

Comment: That answers it all... Thanks